# Missing Links in Table of Contents

Tags: xetex

I am using moderncv with some custom modifications. Unfortunately, the table of contents is missing links to the chapters.

I created a minified example which consists of the following files:

- example.tex

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{moderncv-additions}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\vfill
\begin{minipage}{1.0\textwidth}
    \section{Inhalt}
    \tableofcontents
\end{minipage}
\newpage
\chapter{Chapter1}{}
\lipsum[1]
\newpage
\chapter{Chapter2 }{}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

- moderncv.cls

```
\DeclareOption{a4paper}{
  \setlength\paperheight{297mm}
  \setlength\paperwidth{210mm}}
\newcommand\@ptsize{}
\DeclareOption{11pt}{\renewcommand\@ptsize{1}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\input{size1\@ptsize.clo}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{url}
\urlstyle{tt}
\AtEndPreamble{
  \RequirePackage[unicode]{hyperref}
  \AtBeginDocument{
    \hypersetup{
   }}
  \pagenumbering{arabic}
}
\newcommand*{\section}[1]{%
 }
\endinput
```

- moderncv-additions.sty

```
\AtEndPreamble{
    \renewcommand*{\contentsline}[4]{%
      #2 \dotfill #3\\
    }
    \newcommand{\chapter}{\@ifstar
                         \chapterStar
                         \chapterNoStar }
    \newcommand*{\chapterNoStar}[2]{%
      {%
       \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1#2}%
       \chapter*{#1}{#2}%
      }%
    }
    \newcommand*{\chapterStar}[2]{%
      {%
        \hfill%
      }%
    }
    \renewcommand*{\@starttoc}[1]{%
      \begingroup
        \makeatletter
        \parskip\z@
        \@input{\jobname.#1}%
        \if@filesw
          \expandafter\newwrite\csname tf@#1\endcsname
          \immediate\openout \csname tf@#1\endcsname \jobname.#1\relax
        \fi
        \@nobreakfalse
      \endgroup
    }
    \def\tableofcontents{\@starttoc{toc}}
}
```

Do you have any idea how to obtain the TOC links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't get toc links because you redefined `\contentsline` to exclude them. The normal definition with hyperref is full of mostly hyperref-related additions. If you are redefining it just to add `\dotfill`, I'd suggest keeping it unchanged, but defining `\l@chapter` to either invoke `\@dottedtocline`

```
\newcommand*\l@chapter{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}
```

or to model `\l@chapter` on what you tried to do with `\contentsline`

```
\newcommand*{\l@chapter}[2]{%
  \noindent #1 \dotfill #2\par
}
```

Then you still need two changes to get proper page links:

1. Since you defined your own simple `\chapter` command, it has no link target, so add `\phantomsection` before `\addcontentsline`.
2. Define the page numbering earlier, so the hyperref package sees it. Take `\pagenumbering{arabic}` out of its `\AtBeginDocument` and let it execute immediately. Several other things would do better that way too.

Your TOC minipage can't fit on the line because there is paragraph indent before it, so use

```
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth} ...
```

Comment: great solution! thank you!